# Quise implementar la librería npm i @react-pdf/renderer y me marca los siguiente errores?

Tags: reactjs, npm

Alguien sabe que mas se necesita!! help me!!
Los errores que marca no se porque son!!
si alguien paso por esto y me pueda ayudar

```
import { pdf } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

 async function ImprimirAnticipo(Data: any) {
    const obj = pdf(
      <RptAnticipo
        Data={Data}
      />
    ).toBlob();
    obj.then(blob => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url, "_blank");
    });
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `npm i stream` tal vez?

Comment: si trate de hacer, pero al final me manda un error de globales

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar tu pregunta con el nuevo error? Con texto, no imagen.